# Binomial again, and again

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, inequalities, integration

Let $\lceil a\rceil=$ the smallest integer $\geq a$, otherwise known as the *ceiling function*. When the arguments are real, interpret $\binom{a}b$ using the Euler's gamma function, $\Gamma$.

Recently, I posted a problem on MO about ["sin-omials"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253703/integral-of-a-sin-omial-coefficients-binomial/253965#253965). Here is another one in the same spirit.

> **QUESTION.** Numerical evidence suggest that 
>   $$\left\lceil \int_0^n\binom{n}x dx\right\rceil=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k.$$
>   If true, how do we prove this?

**REMARK.** The RHS evaluates to $2^n$; I only want to stress parallelism between the integral and sum.

Comment: Probably relevant:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x} \, dx = 2^n $$
exactly.
In fact it equals
$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty {n \choose k+x} $ for any real $x$.
See my accepted answer to Question 632219 in Math Stackexchange
<http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633219> .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Interesting. BTW, the link is broken.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check the link in time.  If you copy/paste just the part from
"math." to "633219" into the browser window it works.  (And it should be
possible to show that the prat of the integral outside $0 \leq x \leq n$
decays fast enough to be in negative but $> -1$.)

Comment: The above link from Noam Elkies can be found at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633219/continuous-generalization-of-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k-2n

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I agree "it should be possible to show ..." But, let's hope to see that.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov it is related but not literally duplicate: the question which you cite does not have integer part.

Comment: Right, but it is equivalent to the statement at the end of my second comment (the integrals outside $[0,n]$ add up to something that's negative but not as negative as $-1$).

Comment: Still, we need a proof.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Following the hint by Noam D. Elkies, we just need to show that the remainder $$R_n:=\int_{-\infty}^0{n!\over\Gamma(n+1-x)\Gamma(1+x)}dx+ \int_n^{+\infty} {n!\over\Gamma(n+1-x)\Gamma(1+x)}dx $$ satisfies $$0\le R_n<1.$$ The integrand writes
$${n!\over\Gamma(n+1-x)\Gamma(1+x)}={n! \over  (n-x)(n-1-x)\dots(1-x)\Gamma(1-x)x\Gamma(x)}={n!\over \pi}{ \sin \pi x \over (n-x)(n-1-x)\dots(1-x)x}.$$
With a linear change of variables it is easy to see that the two integrals above coincide,  so that the remainder takes the  form
$$R_n= {2n!\over\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty} {{ \sin \pi x \over x(x+1)\dots(x+n)}}\, dx  $$

so in particular $R_0=1$. If we further write the integral as a Leibnitz alternating sum of the integrals over unit intervals, we find
$$ R_n= {2n!\over\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\; (-1)^k\int_{0}^{1} {{ \sin \pi x \over (x+k)\dots(x+k+n)}}\, dx$$
$$ ={2n!\over\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sin \pi x\bigg[ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\;  {{ 1 \over (x+2k)\dots(x+2k+n)}}-{{ 1 \over (x+2k+1)\dots(x+2k+1+n)}}\bigg]\, dx $$
$$ ={2\over\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sin \pi x \bigg[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\;  {{ (n+1)! \over (x+2k)\dots(x+2k+1+n)}} \bigg]\, dx. $$
This way it is apparent that $R_n$ is positive and strictly decreasing w.r.to $n$, and we conclude that for $n\ge1$
$$0< R_n< R_0=1.$$

Answer (score 24):

Here is a proof which doesn't use the identity $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x}\,dx= 2^n$:

Using the representation ${ n \choose x}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ixt}\left(1+e^{it}\right)^n\,dt$ (valid for $n,x\in\mathbb{R}, n>-1$) we find
\begin{align*}
\int_0^n {n \choose x}\,dx&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^n\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ixt}\left(1+e^{it}\right)^n\,dt\,dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1-e^{-int}}{it}\left(1+e^{it}\right)^n\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{e^{ikt}-e^{-i(n-k)t}}{it}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{e^{ikt}-e^{-ikt}}{it}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{\sin(kt)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \int_{0}^\pi\frac{\sin(kt)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \mathrm{Si}(k\pi) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (*)
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{Si}(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt$ denotes the sine integral. For $a\geq 0$ the sine integral has the representation
$$\mathrm{Si}(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} - \cos(a)\,\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-at}}{1+t^2}\,dt - \sin(a)\,\int_{0}^\infty \frac{t\,e^{-at}}{1+t^2}\,dt$$
Plugging this into $(*)$ (and using $\sin(k\pi)=0,\, \cos(k\pi)=(-1)^k$) we arrive at
$$\int_0^n {n \choose x}\,dx=2^n - \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{-\pi t})^n}{1+t^2} \,dt=:2^n - R_n$$
Clearly the sequence $(R_n)$ is nonnegative, strictly decreasing and $R_0=1$.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another proof of the key integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x} \, dx = 2^n
$$
for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, which is elementary modulo the classical definite integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin t \, \frac{dt}{t} = \pi.
$$
To my surprise, with a bit more work we also get what might be
a new derivation of the latter formula as well.

Start from **Pietro Majer**'s rewriting of $n \choose x$ as
$$
\frac{n!}{\pi} \, \frac{\sin \pi x}{(n-x)(n-1-x) \cdots (1-x) x}
$$
(which we can take as the *definition* of $n \choose x$ for real $x$,
thus replacing the Gamma function with a more elementary trigonometric
function; note that the last factor in the denominator is $x$, not $0-x$).
Now expand in partial fractions:
$$
\frac1{(n-x)(n-1-x) \cdots (1-x) x} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i}{x-i},
$$
to get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x} \, dx
 = \frac{n!}{\pi} \sum_{i=0}^n
   c_i \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin \pi x \, \frac{dx}{x-i}.
$$
The integral is
$(-1)^i \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin \pi x \, \frac{dx}{x} = (-1)^i \pi$, so
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x} \, dx = n! \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i c_i.
$$
But $c_i$ can be computed by letting $x \to i$ in the
partial fraction expansion; we find that $(1)^i n! c_i = {n \choose i}$, so
finally
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x} \, dx = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} = 2^n,
$$
as claimed.

---

---

Now suppose we didn't know the value, call it $I$, of
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin t \, \frac{dt}{t}$.
Then our analysis still gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x} \, dx = \frac{I}{\pi} 2^n.
$$
But I claim that for large even $n$ the integral is asymptotic to $2^n$,
whence $I=\pi$.  The idea is:

---

i) the Riemann sum $\sum_{x=-\infty}^\infty {n \choose x}$ is $2^n$ exactly;

ii) the integral of ${n \choose x} \, dx$ over $x$ outside the interval
$[0,n]$ is asymptotically small compared with $2^n$; and

iii) the integral from $0$ to $n$ is within $n \choose n/2$ of
the Riemann sum $\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}$, and is thus asymptotic to $2^n$.

---

Now (i) is just the binomial expansion of $(1+1)^n$, which we've used already,
while (ii) was already proved by **Pietro Majer** (in fact he obtained a
much stronger bound of $1$, while we need only $o(2^n)$ which is easier to prove).
It remains to show (iii).  But this requires only that $n \choose x$
is increasing on $0 < x < n/2$ and decreasing on $n/2 < x < n$
(we can then compare the integral with the lower and upper Riemann sums).
But we readily see from the product formula for $\sin \pi x$ that
$\log{n \choose x}$ is concave downwards on $0 < x < n$;
since this function is symmetric about $x=n/2$, we conclude that
it is increasing on $x<n/2$ and decreasing on $x>n/2$, **QED**.

Comment: this is very very nice

Comment: The starting point for the second part, that is the identity $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {n\choose x}dx={2^n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {0\choose x}dx={2^n\over \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\sin\pi x\over x}dx,$ may also be derived inductively, integrating ${n\choose x}={n-1\choose x}+{n-1\choose x-1}.$

Comment: I like the simplicity here.

Comment: Also, if we adopt the trigonometric definition of $ {n\choose x}$, the relation ${n-1\choose x}+ {n-1 \choose x-1}= {n\choose x}$ may be derived from the identity:
$${1\over(n-1-x)\dots(1-x)\cdot x}-{1\over(n-x)\dots(2-x)\cdot(x-1)}={n\over(n-x)(n-1-x)\dots(1-x)\cdot x}$$
multiplying by $\sin\pi x=-\sin\pi(x-1)$

Answer (score 5):

The $2^n$ result in Noam Elkies answer generalizes to $n=s$ for $real(s)>-1$, as he notes in MSE. In this range, the generalized binomial coefficient $ \binom{s}{\alpha}$ is a Fourier band-limited fct. in $\alpha$, or, equivalently a sinc fct. interpolation of the sequence $\binom{s}{n}$. See my notes "[Fractional calculus and interpolation of generalized binomial coefficients](http://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/fractional-calculus-and-sinc-function-interpolation-of-generalized-binomial-coefficients/)" for simple derivations and my contribution to the MO-Q [Generalizing a problem to make it easier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40005/generalizing-a-problem-to-make-it-easier/214542#214542) for the integral of the sinc fct. over infinte limits, also simply derived.

The Wikipedia article on the classic [Gibbs phenomena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) explores the extrema of $Si(x)$, easily visualized as a convolution of the sinc with the rectangle function, and, therefore, bounds on the residual of the ceiling.

The sinc function interpolation is an important illustration of the [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97180/history-of-the-sampling-theorem/97202#97202) and a special case of a generalized Chu-Vandermonde identity using Euler's reflection formula for the gamma/factorial function. (I remember long ago reading somewhere that Ramanujan noted this. Anyone know a ref? This would be simple check for his Master Theorem/Formula.)

Comment: Since it is band-limited, we could also interpolate from the samples $\binom{s}{n+\beta}$, for fractional $\beta $, summing over all the integers, negative and positive, and get the same results.