# References for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\binom{1}{t}^3\,\mathrm dt=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ and related integrals?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

In user dxdydz's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3513155/53283) to the question "Unexpected appearances of $\pi^{2}/6$", the identity $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\binom{1}{t}^3\,\mathrm dt=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{6}{\pi^2}$$ is mentioned.

Here, we employ a [generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments) of the binomial coefficients to real arguments: $$\binom{x}{y} := \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)} = \frac{1}{(x+1)B(y+1,x-y+1)} ,$$ where $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

I hadn't seen an integral quite like this one before. It turns out Ramanujan did work on it - as dxdydz states, it comes up in both Part 1 (p. 302 - 304) and Part 2 (p. 225-227) of his Notebooks.

In the answer to a version of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486662/references-for-int-infty-infty-binom1t3-mathrm-dt-frac32-fra) I asked on MSE, user Marco Cantarini points out that: $$I(n,\alpha,l) := \int_{\mathbb{R}}\dbinom{n}{\alpha x}^{\ell}dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\dbinom{n}{\alpha k}^{\ell},\,0<\alpha\leq2/\ell,\,\ell\in\mathbb{N}$$ and that a proof can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255758/integral-of-power-of-binomials-equal-to-sum-of-power-of-binomials) on MO.

I wonder, though, if there are any articles or books that delve into such integrals involving binomial coefficients more elaborately. In particular, I'm interested in descriptions detailing how to find a closed form for $I(1,1,l)$ with $l\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$. Do you know any references?

Comment: These are special cases of Mellin Barnes Integrals. You can work with them through Fox-H function that was implemented in Wolfram's Mathematica recently.

Answer (score 4):

**comment**
$$
\binom{t}{1} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(2-t)} = \frac{\sin((t+1)\pi)}{t(t-1)\pi}
$$
Using this, Maple does the indefinite integrals in terms of the functions ${\rm Si}$ and ${\rm Ci}$.  Taking limits at $\pm \infty$ the first few results are
$$
I\left( 1,1,1 \right) =2,\\
I\left( 1,1,2 \right) =2,\\
I\left( 1,1,3
 \right) ={\frac{3}{2}}+6\,{\pi}^{-2},\\
I\left( 1,1,4 \right) ={\frac{4
}{3}}+10\,{\pi}^{-2},\\
I\left( 1,1,5 \right) ={\frac{115}{96}}+{\frac {
75}{8\,{\pi}^{2}}}+{\frac {105}{2\,{\pi}^{4}}},\\
I\left( 1,1,6 \right) 
={\frac{11}{10}}+{\frac {21}{2\,{\pi}^{2}}}+{\frac {189}{2\,{\pi}^{4}}
},\\
I\left( 1,1,7 \right) ={\frac{5887}{5760}}+{\frac {539}{48\,{\pi}^{
2}}}+{\frac {735}{8\,{\pi}^{4}}}+{\frac {1155}{2\,{\pi}^{6}}},
\\I\left( 1,1,8 \right) ={\frac{302}{315}}+12\,{\pi}^{-2}+110\,{\pi}^{-4
}+{\frac {2145}{2\,{\pi}^{6}}},\\
I\left( 1,1,9 \right) ={\frac{259723}{
286720}}+{\frac {13005}{1024\,{\pi}^{2}}}+{\frac {63855}{512\,{\pi}^{4
}}}+{\frac {135135}{128\,{\pi}^{6}}}+{\frac {225225}{32\,{\pi}^{8}}},
\\
I\left( 1,1,10 \right) ={\frac{15619}{18144}}+{\frac {1925}{144\,{\pi}
^{2}}}+{\frac {13585}{96\,{\pi}^{4}}}+{\frac {125125}{96\,{\pi}^{6}}}+
{\frac {425425}{32\,{\pi}^{8}}}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps some CAS can help discern a general pattern in these results