# Approximation of sum of the first binomial coefficients for fixed N

Tags: co.combinatorics, na.numerical-analysis, binomial-coefficients

I'd like to compute $\sum_{i=0}^k {{N}\choose{i}}$. Is there a computable approximation for that?

Comment: At first change your sigma to a definite integral by method of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254881/binomial-again-and-again) and after that use some approximation method about the definite integral.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of 'the first k' binomial coefficients for fixed n](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n)

Answer (score 17):

One of the more convenient and popular approximations of the sum is

$$\frac{2^{nH(\frac{k}{n})}}{\sqrt{8k(1-\frac{k}{n})}} \leq \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i} \leq 2^{nH(\frac{k}{n})}$$

for $0< k < \frac{n}{2}$, where $H$ is the binary entropy function. (The upper bound is exactly what Aryeh Kontorovich mentions.) You can find its proof in many textbooks, but probably I first learned it from Chapter 10 of *The Theory of Error-Correcting Codes* by MacWilliams and Sloane.

Also, [this post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17202/27829) asks a similar question and is a good resource for the sum in my opinion. You can find several other useful bounds there.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the upper bound. That's probably as well as you can do, with such simple estimates.

Comment: I like the word "popular". :)

Answer (score 13):

A well-known upper bound, for $k\le N/2$, is
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k {N\choose i} \le 2^{N H(k/N)},$$
where $H$ is the binary entropy function
$$ H(x) = -x\log_2(x)-(1-x)\log_2(1-x).$$
This bound was sharpened in Lemma 5 of
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X12000544 (
*Gottlieb, Lee-Ad; Kontorovich, Aryeh; Mossel, Elchanan*, [**VC bounds on the cardinality of nearly orthogonal function classes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2012.01.030), Discrete Math. 312, No. 10, 1766-1775 (2012). [ZBL1242.05050](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.05050).)

Comment: The sharpening adds a prefactor of $0.98$; the authors comment that a smaller prefactor is possible with a more careful/detailed proof. The paper is also available, open access, on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4915; there it is Lemma 7.1, in Section 7